# Can I modify this query using a WITH clause?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have written the following query in order to achieve the following:

1) Select all regulatory languages that do not have a specified `ID`.

2) Link those regulatory languages based on a hierarchy field (`RL_ID_DEFINED` - this field is the `ID` of the parent regulatory language).

My first variation used `NOT IN`, but after looking into it I decided that `NOT EXISTS` would be a more efficient approach.  Additionally, I was thinking that adding a `WITH` clause might make it run a bit faster, since in my current code it is running the nested `SELECT` statement for each `ID` in the iteration.  Would it be possible to rewrite with using a `WITH` clause for that nested `SELECT`?

```
SELECT
    T1.ID 
FROM
    REGULATORY_LANGUAGES T1
WHERE
    T1.INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            REGULATORY_LANGUAGES T2,
            REVIEW_REGULATIONS T3
        WHERE
            T3.RVWTYPYR_ID = ? 
            AND T3.RL_ID = T2.ID
            AND T1.ID = T2.ID)
START WITH
    RL_ID_DEFINED IS NULL
    AND INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR ID = RL_ID_DEFINED
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I look at the structure of a `WITH` clause, I would be creating it prior to my main `SELECT`.  However, that would require me to have defined my `T1` table already.  Any thoughts?

(Note - this is being called in a java method, hence the `?` in the line `T3.RVWTYPYR_ID = ?`.  When I test this in the database editor via Toad, I just hard code a value for the `?`).

Comment: "I was thinking that adding a WITH clause might make it run a bit faster," Where do you get this idea ? WITH clause is mostly for organization .. not really for performance (there are possibly some side cases where it helps, but I wouldn't normally consider WITH when looking at performance) ;)

Comment: It was my understanding that the `WITH` clause would only be run once, instead of (in my case) the nested `SELECT` which has to be run for each `ID` that I am iterating.  This guy made a pretty good case for why I was trying to incorporate it:  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql99_with_clause.htm

Comment: You should certainly try to avoid correlated subqueries when possible because they do have to run for each row in the outer results. Using `WITH` isn't the way to do that though. It's usually through the use of `JOIN`s or some other method. Otherwise you run into your exact issue - you still need to relate the one query to the other with the ID.

Comment: If you can provide some sample data with expected output then perhaps someone can provide a better solution. Also, you should use the `JOIN` syntax when writing SQL instead of putting all of your tables in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @QuestionMarks: Yeah, I don't read much from that guy, don't really trust his opinions. (and Tom H answered rest of your quesitons ... ) ;)

Comment: @TomH - thanks for the info. I think a `LEFT JOIN' should accomplish what I'm looking for. I'm admittedly pretty weak in the SQL department so I appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks to Tom H for his insight.  I've rewritten the query using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    T1.ID
FROM
    REGULATORY_LANGUAGES T1
LEFT JOIN (      
    SELECT
        T2.ID ID
    FROM
        REGULATORY_LANGUAGES T2
    INNER JOIN    
        REVIEW_REGULATIONS T3
    ON
        T3.RVWTYPYR_ID = ?
        AND T3.RL_ID = T2.ID) T_JOIN
ON T1.ID = T_JOIN.ID             
WHERE
    T1.INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL
    AND T_JOIN.ID IS NULL
START WITH
    T1.RL_ID_DEFINED IS NULL
    AND T1.INACTIVE_DATE IS NULL 
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR T1.ID = T1.RL_ID_DEFINED
```

Answer (score 0):

While speed is important, so is accuracy.  You mentioned that you switched from `not in` to `not exists` for efficiency.  They do different things.  There is another way to speed up the logic of `not in`.  Instead of this:

```
where someField not in 
(select someField
from etc
)
```

Do this

```
where someField in 
(select someField
from etc
where whatever
minus
select someField
from etc
where whatever
and more filters that identify records to exclude
)
```

Now for the `with` keyword.  It speeds up performance when you want to run the exact same subquery more than once.  So, instead of this:

```
where field1 in 
(sql for subquery)
and field 2 in 
(exact same sql as above)
```

you do this:

```
with temp as (sql for subquery)
select etc
where field1 in 
(select something from temp)
and field 2 in 
(select something from temp)
```

However, that's not your situation.  What you probably want to do is to investigate ways to send a list of parameters from java so that your query looks like this:

```
T3.RVWTYPYR_ID in (?,?,etc)
```

Then you wouldn't have to repeat the subquery.